# Should I use a custom flag instead of a spam flag for not obvious spam?

Tags: support, declined-flags, spam

One of my spam flags, referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649181/integers-of-unlimited-size/62554127#62554127) (mods can see deleted posts, right?) was declined with the *"found no evidence to support it"* motivation.

I flagged the post as spam because of the following:

- it was two lines long
- did not provide a full answer to the question
- it included a link to a YouTube video
- I investigated and found out that the YouTube account who posted the video has the same name and picture of the SO account.
- the SO post did not disclose affiliation

So that seemed spam to me. Did I use the spam flag incorrectly? If the spam flag was correct, was it declined because the reviewer maybe didn't follow the link? In that case, would it be better to use a custom flag, to point out my evidence?

Thank you

Comment: _mods can see deleted posts, right?_ yeah, we see _everything_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I declined that flag and I did look at the video. It didn't look to me like the OP's *intent* was to promote their video (and I looked at their other posts as well to check it wasn't a "thing" they were doing) but was rather a (ill-guided) attempt to genuinely answer the question - albeit it in a format that isn't useful for SO. Hence, I declined the flag, but deleted the post. It would probably have ended up being deleted in review anyway as it had been flagged as VLQ.

Comment: It was actionable, so why not mark it as helpful or disputed?

Comment: @Dharman yeah - that's fair enough, I undeleted, spam flagged it myself, disputed the red flags, then re-deleted. So it will now show as disputed.

Answer (score 7):

We flag as spam when there is an indication that it was posted only to promote some website or a service. Sometimes you can figure by a single post that the author has bad intentions, but sometimes it is not clear. If you see the user post multiple similar links then it clearly means they want to promote their YouTube channel.

If it is not clear that this was intended to be spam then just flag as Not an answer and let it be deleted. The user probably didn't know that this is not the appropriate way of providing an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Jon's answer, you should use the spam flag **when there's something relatively obvious to the spam**. Things like

> Thanks! Great Job! [My SEO keywords here](/#)

That's fairly blatant. If the user

- Copies other content
- Posts their own content without proper disclosure
- Has a non-obvious pattern of spam

use a custom flag.

Comment: re: *"Posts their own content without proper disclosure"* - if they don't do this _routinely_, i.e. it's a one-off from a quick look through their posts, it may not even be necessary to flag and a friendly comment asking them to add disclosure in future can often cover it